# does vb 6 generate the same output file if the code has not been modified

Tags: vb6, compilation

Assume that I have the source codes of a vb6 project and the executable compiled by the vendor.  I want to make sure that the executable given by the vendor is the executable that is generated by exactly this project.
If I compile the project myself should I expect to obtain exactly the same output file, even if I don't change any single source code or project property, or is it normal to get a slightly different output file. 
Should the checksums of the file given to me and the one compiled by me match? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, the projects will differ.  Things like the date and time are compiled into the project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I verify that the compiled executable is the output of this project, source code?

Comment: Other than keeping a hash of every build, you really don't have a way to tell from an executable if it was built with the source code.